# How to escape Jquery form validation from the same form element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to used form validation to valid all the form element but I want to escape one of those if one checkbox is checked.

**HTML**

```
<form id="reg_form">
       <div class="control-group">
        <div class="control">
           <label class="control-label"  for="sex"> Male </label>
              <?PHP echo form_checkbox('sex', 1, '', 'class="example"') ?>
           <label class="control-label"  for="sex"> Female </label>
              <?PHP echo form_checkbox('sex', 2, '', 'class="example"') ?>
        </div>       
    </div>      
   </form>
```

Jquery Valition

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#reg_form").validate({
          rules:{
                sex:{
                    required:true,
                   }
          },messages:{
                sex:"Please select sex "
                   }
      })
})
```

Thanks

Comment: You should use a radio group instead of 2 checkboxes.

Comment: So it may can't with check box right. But ok thanks it is ok i will using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When user should select only one option you should use a radio group or a non-multiple `select` element instead of several checkboxes. This also solves the validation issue.